# Composer: use specific commit of your own fork of a third party library

Tags: git, github, composer-php

With following way I can use forked repo (sampleRepo) with no problem.

```
   "require": {
        "some-one-else/sampleRepo": "dev-master"
    },

  "repositories": [{
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/my-git/sampleRepo"
        }
  ]
```

I have changed few things on forked repo and released more than one version.

My question is how can I load specific commit or version from updated fork?

I need to load release v1.0

**OR**

commit reference (db11221) **from forked repo.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links):

> `require` and `require-dev` additionally support explicit references
>   (i.e. commit) for dev versions to make sure they are locked to a given
>   state, even when you run update. These only work if you explicitly
>   require a dev version and append the reference with `#<ref>`.

So simply try:

```
   "require": {
        "some-one-else/sampleRepo": "dev-master#db11221"
    },

  "repositories": [{
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/my-git/sampleRepo"
        }
  ]
```

Take a look at this note also:

> `Note`: This feature has severe technical limitations, as the
>   composer.json metadata will still be read from the branch name you
>   specify before the hash. You should therefore only use this as a
>   temporary solution during development to remediate transient issues,
>   until you can switch to tagged releases. The Composer team does not
>   actively support this feature and will not accept bug reports related
>   to it.

Comment: Thanks. it didn't worked when I tried while ago but now working somehow.